# Python - Match and change datatime

Tags: python, csv

Good Morning,
I am trying to read a list and recognize strings with datetime-format. Here is an example of my list (with datetime or version number):

- String, 1.0.1
- String2, 2017-10-03
- String3, 2014-12-01
- String4, 01.11.2017

Now I want to change 2014-12-01 to 01.12.2014. It works fine with this code:

```
dfnew[1].iloc[i]=datetime.datetime.strptime(dfnew[1].iloc[i], "%Y-%m-%d").strftime("%d.%m.%Y")
```

But if I use this code here:

```
for i, x in dfnew.iterrows():
    print (dfnew[1].iloc[i])
    if ( (dfnew[1].iloc[i]) == (datetime.datetime.strptime(dfnew[1].iloc[i], "%YY-%mm-%d")) ):
        dfnew[1].iloc[i]=datetime.datetime.strptime(dfnew[1].iloc[i], "%Y-%m-%d").strftime("%d.%m.%Y")
```

I get the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "CVE_List.py", line 74, in <module>
    if ( (dfnew[1].iloc[i]) == (datetime.datetime.strptime(dfnew[1].i
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\lib\_strptime.py", line 56
    tt, fraction = _strptime(data_string, format)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\lib\_strptime.py", line 36
    (data_string, format))
ValueError: time data '1.0.1' does not match format '%Y-%m-%d'
```

But normally the row with format x.y.z have to be ignored.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dont use `iterrows` if not necessary, because very slow. Better is use pandas vectorized function.

Here the best is use [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html) with parameter `errors='coerce'` for convert not parseable datetimes to `NaT`.

If need convert to custom string format add [`dt.strftime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.strftime.html):

```
print (df)
         0           1
0   String       1.0.1
1  String2  2017-10-03
2  String3  2014-12-01
3  String4  01.11.2017

df[1] = pd.to_datetime(df[1], errors='coerce')
print (df)
         0          1
0   String        NaT
1  String2 2017-10-03
2  String3 2014-12-01
3  String4 2017-01-11
```

EDIT:

General solution need distingush [all possible formats](http://strftime.org/) of dates with `year`s, dates without `years` and then [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html) them to `df1` DataFrame. Last for each row remove `NaN`s and add `versions` by [`combine_first`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.combine_first.html):

```
#remove trailing whitespaces 
c = df[1].str.strip()

dates_formats_with_years = ['%Y-%m-%d','%d.%m.%Y']
d1 = [pd.to_datetime(c, errors='coerce', format=x) for x in dates_formats_with_years]
s1 = [s.dt.strftime("%#d.%#m")
          .add('.')
          .add(s.dt.strftime("%y").str.lstrip('0'))
          .str.rstrip('.')
          .replace('NaT.NaT', np.nan) for s in d1]

dates_formats_no_years = ['%d.%b']
d2 = [pd.to_datetime(c, errors='coerce', format=x) for x in dates_formats_no_years]
s2 = [s.dt.strftime("%#d.%#m").replace('NaT', np.nan) for s in d2]
```

---

```
df1 = pd.concat(s1 + s2, axis=1, keys=range(len(s1) + len(s2)))
print (df1)
         0   1   2
0      NaN NaN NaN
1      NaN NaN NaN
2   3.5.29 NaN NaN
3   2.8.17 NaN NaN
4      NaN NaN NaN
5      5.6 NaN NaN
6    3.4.7 NaN NaN
7      NaN NaN NaN
8   7.6.17 NaN NaN
9    4.1.1 NaN NaN
10   1.8.3 NaN NaN
11     NaN NaN NaN
12     NaN NaN NaN
13     NaN NaN NaN
14   1.2.8 NaN NaN

df[1] = df1.apply(lambda x: x.sort_values().iat[0], axis=1).combine_first(c)
print (df)
                               0                  1
0                      alsa-intf  UMC-9240P_D_v0.30
1                       alsa-lib             1.0.29
2                    base-passwd             3.5.29
3                     sshfs-fuse             2.8.17
4   start-scripts-firmware-links                1.0
5                              s                5.6
6                      syslog-ng              3.4.7
7                    system-conf  UMC-9240P_D_v0.30
8                   tcp-wrappers             7.6.17
9                        tcpdump              4.1.1
10                     tinyproxy              1.8.3
11                    tinyscheme              1.0.0
12                useradd-peiker                1.0
13                    util-linux             2.26.2
14                          zlib              1.2.8
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/159490/discussion-on-answer-by-jezrael-python-match-and-change-datatime).